# how to setup BjyAuthorize in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, acl, zend-framework2

I'm trying to use [BjyAuthorize](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize) in a sample application in ZF2 and I have a bit of an issue setting it up.

I have an `Admin` module and I want to give permissions for the user to access it.
I also have the `ZfcUser` module and that one seems to work just fine with this acl.

The way I set up the db's is like his:

```
user_role
role_id     default     parent
------------------------------
user        1           admin
admin       2           NULL


user_role_linker
user_id     role_id
-------------------
1           user
```

I'm not sure this is set up correctly, also I'm not sure why `role_id` is a varchar ??!!

In any case, with this setup the ZfcUser works just fine.

The problem is when I try to use a different module, where I add:

```
array('controller' => 'Admin\Controller\Index', 'roles' => array('guest','user'))
```

I get

> 403 Forbidden
>   You are not authorized to access Admin\Controller\Admin ::indexAction() .

In the README file it is mentioned that I could use `$this->isAllowed($resource[, $privilege])` in my controller or view, but that code is wrong and I'm not sure what is the `$resource` or the `$privilege`

So I guess my question is how can I use this module? Did anyone got it to work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i found a solution that lets me work with ZfcUser and BjyAuthorize called [ZfcUser-BjyAuthorize-Bridge](https://github.com/darkmatus/roleuserbridge)

Also managed to make the modules work with the roles just by fallowing the BjyAuthorisation documentation again and again and again.

I set up a testing environment on github [here](https://github.com/patrioticcow/Zend-Project) that prettily much works as a starting point with all those modules.

note: this module will change as it's more of a playground for me

Answer (score 0):

According to 403 error text, most likely your rule should be changed to

```
array('controller' => 'Admin\Controller\Admin', 'action' => 'index', 'roles' => array('guest', 'user'))
```